# What is the best way to create an Application Release Automation tool with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

**NOTE: I am not entirely sure whether I am posting this in the right section on Stack, but after a bit of research I deemed it appropriate - please let me know if this belongs somewhere else and I will immediately delete and re-post this**

So for my university project I have to make a tool like [XL Release](https://xebialabs.com/products/application-release-orchestration-xl-release/) using Visual Studio. Now, as I am still lacking experience, I am unsure how to develop this. I don't know which way would be the most appropriate and easy to re-create a tool like XL Release, but with less functionality.

In case you were wondering what kind of tool I must create and if you can't bother looking through the documentation, I will make a short summary here. There will be users with like 3-4 roles, each role having access to certain things. The purpose of such a tool is to help developers keep track of their tasks, the dependencies and pre-conditions that have to be respected before the task is "Done", the phases through which every task goes and the environment (Acceptance, Development, Testing, Deployment) that an application is in.

Therefore, I came up with a few ideas of how I should get this project underway, but I need some of your advice.

1. Should I make a **WEB API** with all the back-end functionality and then call it using an **ASP.NET Core Web Application**?
2. Should I make an **ASP.NET Web Application** (.NET Framework) with **MVC**?
3. Should I create an **ASP.NET Core Web Application**? As you can see here, I can't really tell the difference between a Core Web App and one using .NET Framework. From my little experience so far, I noticed that some of the methods were different. But that's basically it.

Which one of the 3 should I pick? Do you have any other solution for my problem?

EDIT: I do realize that this question is very subjective. I was wondering if such a tool could be created much easier using a certain way, rather than going through all of them and risking not to complete my assignment. All I am asking for is some feedback that could help me get my mind straight. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Option 1 is better as this will give you a flavour of how the backend and frontend are integrated and kept separate. I would also advise creating multiple web apis for different functionalities.

Comment: For you, the easiest way is the programming language that you are most familiar with. If the only constraint is "Visual Studio" then it doesn't even need to be a web app (which has it's own challenges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right this question is little subjective. I will give you reasons for the technology you should pick:

1. **Asp.NET Core Web API + Front end in React or Angular** : Here you will detach the user interface from the back end so in future if you think you want to release a mobile version of your application then you just need to make small app which can communicate with the Web API. Also you can test both the layers separately.
2. **Asp.NET Core Web Application (with MVC)**: If you want both the front end and back end in the same solution then you need to go for this one.
3. **Asp.NET Framework web application (with MVC)**: This comes with the hosting difference. If you think you will host your application in windows only then choose this else you need to pick option 2.
4. **Asp.NET Framework web application (without MVC)**: This is old technology and I will not suggest to use it as it makes the site very heavy, everybody is trying to move away from it.

Also if you think you gonna have too many hits on your application then you can use some Microservices too.

Let me know if I can provide any other help to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I really appreciate the explanation for each option. I will keep them in mind when getting the project started!

Comment: It would be great if you can mark it as answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Sure! I have another question, though - would it be alright if at point 1: I use ASP.NET Core Web API for backend and a Web Application with Razor Pages for the frontend? I didn't use React or Angular until now and I don't know how complicated it would be.

Comment: No, it will not work. You need to go with point 2. You can not create separate application for only razor(UI). In the same application you can use MVC+ Razor.